# DirectShow Virtual Camera does not appear in the list on some configurations

Tags: c#, google-chrome, camera, windows-10, directshow

I'm using DirectShow filter as virtual camera (CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory). It's working good but some apps/configurations do not display this feed as source. For example on win 8.1 I can see this source in Chrome/Firefox via webrtc. But in win 10 - chrome does not show this source in the list (but FF does). Also adobe flash does not show it in the list everywhere. What is important for me now is to make it available on win 10 /chrome. What may affect on this and how to fix it?

**Update**

Looks like there are two different sets of filters for x86 and x64. So the poblem with chrome was caused by different architecture. But flash still not detect camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectShow virtual cameras are only visible to same bitness applications, which consume video capture using DirectShow (or, in some cases, Video for Windows). If you have a bitness problem, you can fix it by building/registering virtual camera for respective bitness. If the application consumes video using Media Foundation, the virtual DirectShow camera won't bee seen/accessible. [Applicability of Virtual DirectShow Sources](http://alax.info/blog/1722) blog post explains this a bit further and with a picture.

Firefox is supposedly using DirectShow, so it might be a bitness problem.

Another problem might be related to Windows 10 Anniversary Update, which changed behavior of DirectShow sources. You might want to apply a registry fix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38936657/868014) to see if it restores the earlier behavior (to find out whether the experienced issue is related to Anniversary Update changes).